# Static subpages with SEO URLs

Tags: php, zend-framework2, zend-framework-routing

How I can serve static .phtml subpage, with parameters definied in db?

For example, I have entry in database:

```
table 'static_subpages' {  
    id: 1  
    url: /author  
    route: module=about;controller=index;action=subpage  
    params: page=author.phtml  
    layout: true  
}
```

This is simple example. Of course, I can create maaaany routes in module.config.php, but I want to dynamic manage pages from database (in admin panel). Very important is SEO URLs: an URL like /about/subpage/author is not better than /author.

Any ideas how I can do it?

Answer (score 1):

You can serve static pages by using an URL Segment in routing config:

In your`module.config.php`:

```
                'static' => array(
                    'type'    => 'Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\Segment',
                    'options' => array(
                        'route'    => 'about/:page_name',
                        'defaults' => array(
                            'controller' => 'About\Controller\Index',
                            'action'     => 'subpage',
                        ),
                    ),
```

In your `About\Controller\IndexController`:

```
/**
 * Render static pages
 *
 * @return \Zend\View\Model\ViewModel
 */
public function staticAction()
{
    $pageName = $this->params('page_name');
    $view = new ViewModel();

    // loads views like view/static/author.phtml
    $view->setTemplate('static/' . $pageName); 

    return $view;
}
```

In your views you can use something like:

```
<a href="<?php echo $this->url('static', array('page_name' => 'author')); ?>">
    Author
</a>
```

This will produce an URL like: `/about/author/`

Comment: Thanks :) but I want have urls in top level, for example `/author`, `/example` etc. and I want to serve static page when route not exist (controller for this is not enabled etc.). How?

Answer (score 0):

Additionally to mihaidoru's answer you dont necessarily need to use '/' you can map parameter's with any delimiter. I have a little example here where I produced some friendly url's without '/':

```
'randomroute' => array(
            'type' => 'segment',
            'options' => array(
                'route'    => '/[:param].:id:.html',
                'constraints' => array(
                    'id'     => '[0-9]+',
                    'param' => '[a-zA-Z-0-9-_\/%]+',
                    ),
                'defaults' => array(
                    'controller' => 'Your\Name\Space',
                    'action'     => 'index',
                    ),   
                ),
            ),
```

In my example any url ending with .html and a Id constraint will be mapped here.

```
your.url.application/test123.01.html or your.url.application/foobar.02.html etc.
```

The `[:param]` is optional in this case indicated by the '[:]'.

This may not exactly what you are looking for since you'll probably need to do this for every route unless you give this url a action parameter which is somewhat causes additional lines of code. I would just go and create it for every route since I feel that the routing configuration works pretty well and should not be that much of a hassle to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

I'm found solution. Thanks for above reply's, but that's not it.

First, I created new module "Subpage" with standard controller and `index` action.
Next, set up router for this:

```
'router' => array(
    'routes' => array(
        'subpage' => array(
            'type' => 'segment',
            'options'   => array(
                'route'     => '/[:page[.html]]',
                'constraints' => array(
                    'page'  => '[a-zA-Z0-9]*',
                ),
                'defaults'  => array(
                    'controller'    => 'Subpage\Controller\Subpage',
                    'action'        => 'index',
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
),
```

But when I'm added module in *application.config.php*, real modules with their routes are not available. Solution is very simple but took me hours of experiments - move Subpage module to first :)

In `application.config.php`:

```
'modules' => array(
    'Subpage',
    'Application',
    'Gallery',
),
```

Now, router trace is:

1. Match URL for existing controllers and routers, going from end of array
2. If not found, try route with `Subpage` controller; `IndexAction` in this module checks database and - when found - serve static page
3. When URL don't match:

   - when in `Subpage -> IndexController -> IndexAction()`: redirect to `ErrorController`
   - or if URL don't match to any modules **and** to router in Subpage module, run `ErrorController`

This is simple for people experienced with ZF2, but not for me. I've not found anything like that.